# How can I get AWS Cognito login/logout to work properly with AWS API Gateway on Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm writing a simple Android app that currently offers the following features:

1. Register/login with email and password, against an [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) back end
2. Logout (against the same Cognito back end)
3. Call a protected web API on [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)

I'm building my own very simple login/logout UI, rather than using the AWS Cognito UI library:

[image: Login and logged-in screens]

*Login screen (left); logged-in screen (right)*

The web API should return 200 (and a body) when the user is logged in, and a 403 error when they are logged out. The server setup all appears to be correct, and an equivalent app on iOS is working as described.

The problem on Android is as follows:

- When I start the app, don't log in, and call the API: I get a 403 error (expected).
- When I log in and call the API again: I still get a 403 error (**unexpected**).
- When I close the app, swipe it from the recent apps list, and re-open it: I'm still logged in (expected)
- Now when I call the API: I get a 200 response (expected).

The same happens now if I log out: I still get a 200 response after logging out until I kill the app and restart it.

**How can I get the API Gateway call to respect my current authentication state immediately, without recycling the app?**

I wondered if the AWS API Gateway Android library might be to blame, so I've tried an alternative implementation using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) but I get exactly the same result. I've based my Cognito code on the [AmazonCognitoYourUserPools demo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo).

Here's the part of my build.gradle that imports the AWS libraries:

```
// AWS Mobile Client
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.18@aar') { transitive = true }

// Cognito UserPools for SignIn
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.6.18@aar') { transitive = true }

// AWS API gateway
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.6.18'
```

It probably won't help to paste large amounts of code here, but I've created gists for the main classes involved (with logging etc. removed to keep them as small and relevant as possible):

- [`LoginActivity.java`](https://gist.github.com/markwhitaker/cdb52922f4956a67d5a2fd406de91212)
- [`LoggedInActivity.java`](https://gist.github.com/markwhitaker/07a624bf535b8c3db861ef9d09ff05f9)
- [`AbstractBaseActivity.java`](https://gist.github.com/markwhitaker/f4e33e33bf0bd99680f52ab44a1d7882)
- [`ApiCaller.java`](https://gist.github.com/markwhitaker/42aba41e3260e9b18261254f6dd7198d)

The `AwsInterceptor` class referenced in `ApiCaller.java` came from [here](https://github.com/Ghedeon/AwsInterceptor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution my colleague and I have arrived at is as follows:

### Login

After login, you need to re-initialise the `AWSMobileClient` before you call any API Gateway endpoints. Here's a snippet from my `AuthenticationHandler` in `LoginActivity.java`:

```
private AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final CognitoUserSession userSession,
                          final CognitoDevice newDevice)
    {
        // Initialise the client again
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(LoginActivity.this, new AWSStartupHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(final AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult)
            {
                switchTo(LoggedInActivity.class);
            }
        }).execute();
    }

    // ...
}
```

### Logout

After logout, we found we needed to clear the credentials from the `IdentityManager`. This snippet is from my `LoggedInActivity.java`:

```
private void logout()
{
    final CognitoUser currentUser = getCurrentUser();
    currentUser.signOut();

    // Clear the IdentityManager credentials
    final IdentityManager idm = new IdentityManager(this, new AWSConfiguration(this));
    IdentityManager.setDefaultIdentityManager(idm);
    idm.getUnderlyingProvider().clearCredentials();
    idm.getUnderlyingProvider().clear();
    idm.getUnderlyingProvider().setLogins(null);

    switchTo(LoginActivity.class);
}
```

Comment: Hi, After the `clearCredentials()` our refresh token is not accessible anymore. Right?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the API Gateway call to respect my current authentication state immediately, without recycling the app?

Try initialize `AWSMobileClient` every time when you call AWS API in [ApiCaller.java](https://gist.github.com/markwhitaker/42aba41e3260e9b18261254f6dd7198d)

```
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSStartupHandler;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSStartupResult;

AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {
        final AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider();
        // .....

    }
}).execute();
```

In my limited experience with AWS Android, I think this is the way to make sure client is ready

Comment: Thanks Paul. Since I posted this question that's exactly what I tried and it works for me too. I needed a different solution to handle logout though, so I'll post an answer that combines both solutions.

Comment: glad you find a solution with your colleague:) and indeed the logout part need to do many clear jobs